# Keep getting blue screen driver errors, but all drivers are up to date

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, crash, hp-envy

I bought an HP Envy x360 last month. For a few days everything was great. I then installed a program called DriverBooster. It said I had many out of date drivers. I clicked on update all drivers. It now says all of my drivers are up to date. However, ever since I updated them, my computer has been crashing for apparently driver related reasons. Some of the error codes I've gotten on the blue screen have been

`Driver Power State Failure`

`DPC Watchdog Violation`

How can I undo what I did? I presume I can factory restore (I have no restore points) but will that bring all the original drivers back? Why does it say all of my drivers are up to date when the drivers give errors? Even in device manager, clicking devices one by one all drivers are apparently up to date. Presumably, this is a driver issue as it only began happening immediately after I updated all drivers.

Comment: IOBit is a shady company. I wouldn’t touch anything they make. If your computer is only a month old, call HP. Or go to the hp.com support site. There’s plenty of information and help available on how to reload your operating system. https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04742289